# Pulling Data as an Entire Month's Sum

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, cumulative-sum

In snowflake I am trying to pull a months worth of select data as a sum for the month. All I can get is the data broken down as summed by each day of the month. How can I get the entire month to sum all dates data as one data total? -Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `date_trunc()`

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/date_trunc.html

It would look something like:

```
SELECT date_trunc('month',date_field) as mnth, SUM(whatever_field) as sm
FROM table_name
GROUP BY 1;
```

Comment: Thank you. So would you add that as a sub-query into the query below?
SELECT
    VisitLocation,
    VisitDate,
    COUNT(visitservicecategory) AS "Massage Services"
FROM
    bv_visitsoverview
WHERE
    visitservicecategory like 'Custom Massage'
AND
    Pricingoptionname <> 'Null'
GROUP BY
    VisitLocation, VisitDate
ORDER BY
    VisitLocation

Comment: try: 

`SELECT VisitLocation, date_trunc('month',visit_date) as visit_date_mo, COUNT(visitservicecategory) AS "Massage Services" FROM bv_visitsoverview WHERE visitservicecategory like 'Custom Massage' AND Pricingoptionname <> 'Null' GROUP BY VisitLocation, visit_date_mo ORDER BY VisitLocation `

Comment: Perfect! Thank you both! Still pretty new to this and have tried about 50 variations. Never considered the "date_trunc" method. Truly, thank you both!